# Pandas: using .replace() in Matt Harrison's book Effective Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, replace, jupyter-notebook

I was going through the book and there is a piece of code that I'm neither able to run nor debug. It's on page 180 if anyone is interested.

So I'm trying to replace a column of type object that has many categories into one value. This is how the table looks:

```
*Company_size*
Just me
More than 5,000
More than 5,000
Not sure
2-10
11-50
51-500
...
```

And the value 'Just me' should be replaced by 1, 'More than 5,000' by 5000, 'Not sure' by NaN, '2-10' by 2, '11-50' by 11 and so on.

The code to replace it is:

```
jb2 = jb[uniq_cols].rename(columns=lambda c: c.replace('.','_')).assign(company_size=lambda df_: df_.company_size.replace({'Just me': 1, 'Not sure':np.nan, 'More than 5,000':5000, '2-10':2, '11-50':11, '51-500':51, '501-1,000':501, '1,001-5,000':1001}))
```

This code involves a step before which is:

1. to use only the relevant columns using the list called uniq_cols and
2. to convert dot into underscores in the column headers

The code converts the first three values which are 'Just me', 'Not sure' and 'More and 5,000' properly. The rest remain the same.

I have tried to use .replace() at a fundamental level to see how it works. The code:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'total revenue':['0-10', '11-100', '101-500', '501-1000']})
>>> df
  total revenue
0          0-10
1        11-100
2       101-500
3      501-1000
>>> df['total revenue'] = df['total revenue'].replace({'0-10':0,'11-100':11,'101-500':101,'501-1000':501})
>>> df['total revenue']
0      0
1     11
2    101
3    501
Name: total revenue, dtype: int64
>>>
```

This works perfectly. I have tried to convert the original column into string from object type before using .replace(). Also tried to add 'inplace=True' in the original code, but they don't work either. I don't know if the code doesn't work inherently or there is some problem in my understanding of the .replace() function.

The [link](https://github.com/mattharrison/datasets/raw/master/data/2020-jetbrains-python-survey.csv) to the dataset.

Comment: Have you checked for whitespace in your column? What happens if you try the code after a `df['company_size'].str.strip()`

Comment: @Mortz just checked it. Doesn't work. I'll look into this problem again sometime later.

Comment: Also, are you running this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows 10. On Jupyter Notebook in VS Code. Python version 3.9.13

Answer (score 0):

It seems the above error is caused due to the use of
Unicode Character En Dash (U+2013) '–' in the provided data which does not match the keyboard entered hyphen sign.

Also, one needs to set the following options:

```
pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)
```

Once done, the code should run without any issues.